# What is the length of the Minimum Spanning Tree

Tags: graph-theory, trees

What is the length of the Minimum Spanning Tree for the following weighted graph?

Solution. The length of any minimum spanning tree for this graph (and there is more
than one) is 60.

The graph and the solution can be seen here
http://oi47.tinypic.com/1zb56w.jpg 
[image]

Can someone explain how to do this problem, I'm having trouble understanding the process of finding the MST

Answer (score 2):

Hint: The algorithm goes this way: Choose the edges weight from the lowest to highest.
That edge will be added if it doesnt form a cycle with already choosen edges.
The algorithm stops when a spanning tree is formed.

Comment: i understand that. what is troubling me is how do i know when im supposed to stop, how do i know a tree is formed, i could easily leave out one branch and call that a MST since it will be smaller then all the branches that were initially counted. also for the solution to the above graph it seemed like they found two sub-graphs instead of one to be the MST. i understand the algorithm you gave, its the actual application of the algorithm that doesn't make sense, based on what i wrote above

Comment: Your MST should include all the vertices in the graph. Check for its cardinality.

Comment: ok i see, its getting more clearer. however doesn't the middle top 4 circled edges with weights 3 4 3 3 (with the non circled edge 4 through the middle ) form a cycle?

Comment: I just noticed it. Tree is a graph which should not contain cycle.

Comment: i guess its just a mistake in the solutions then